# Run exe file on EC2 from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a requirement to run a .exe file with the SQS event message as parameter. The .exe is installed on EC2. Is it possible to invoke the exe from the AWS Lamda function?

Comment: Do you have the source code for the .exe, so you might be able to rewrite it in Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to run scripts on EC2 instances from *outside* of the EC2 instance is probably to use [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html).

The setup is fairly simple:

1. your EC2 instance needs to include the [SSM Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html) (it probably already does if it was launched from an Amazon-provided Amazon Linux or Ubuntu AMI)
2. your EC2 instance needs to be launched with an IAM role with an attached AmazonEC2RoleforSSM policy, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-configuring-access-role.html)
3. your Lambda function needs an IAM role allowing it to invoke Run Command (the action is ssm:SendCommand)

Alternatively, you could do this in other ways, for example:

1. use [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) or [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) to exec commands over SSH
2. install a web server on the EC2 instance that allows you to remotely invoke an API to execute the script